# External API auth should be a ServiceProvider or Controller in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Im building an app using Laravel, that app will allow the customers to send and get contacts from/to Mautic (email marketing software) via API, but first the app need to get an autorization to use Mautic API and store the user credintals to database for future use.

This is an example for how i make an autorization to connect to that api

```
$settings = [
    'userName'   => '',             // Create a new user       
    'password'   => '',             // Make it a secure password
];

// Initiate the auth object specifying to use BasicAuth
$initAuth = new ApiAuth();
$auth     = $initAuth->newAuth($settings, 'BasicAuth');
```

and then i can get the contact by id using this

```
$api        = new MauticApi();  //This class is from the API package
$contactApi = $api->newApi('contacts', $auth, $apiUrl);
$response = $contactApi->get($id);
```

So my question is how can i organize that logic, should i just put all of it in a controller or it's better to create a service provider which should be responsible of the autorization and then return $auth handle that i can use then later for each customer, and if it's better to user the serviceprovider approch then i'm wondering how can i do that, should i just put  the autorization logic in the boot method?